# MySQL query for items where average price is less than X?

Tags: mysql, average

I'm stumped with how to do the following purely in MySQL, and I've resorted to taking my result set and manipulating it in ruby afterwards, which doesn't seem ideal.

Here's the question. With a dataset of 'items' like:

```
id  state_id  price  issue_date  listed
1   5         450    2011        1
1   5         455    2011        1
1   5         490    2011        1 
1   5         510    2012        0
1   5         525    2012        1
...
```

I'm trying to get something *like*:

```
SELECT * FROM items 
WHERE ([some conditions], e.g. issue_date >= 2011 and listed=1) 
 AND state_id = 5
GROUP BY id
HAVING AVG(price) <= 500
ORDER BY price DESC 
LIMIT 25
```

Essentially I want to grab a "group" of items whose average price fall under a certain threshold. I know that my above example "group by" and "having" are not correct since it's just going to give the `AVG(price)` of that one item, which doesn't really make sense. I'm just trying to illustrate my desired result.

The important thing here is I want *all* of the individual items in my result set, I don't just want to see one row with the average price, total, etc.

Currently I'm just doing the above query without the `HAVING AVG(price)` and adding up the individual items one-by-one (in ruby) until I reach the desired average. It would be really great if I could figure out how to do this in SQL. Using subqueries or something clever like joining the table onto itself are certainly acceptable solutions if they work well! Thanks!

**UPDATE:** In response to Tudor's answer below, here are some clarifications. There is always going to be a target quantity in addition to the target average. And we would always sort the results by price low to high, and by date.

So if we did have 10 items that were all priced at $5 and we wanted to find 5 items with an average < $6, we'd simply return the first 5 items. We wouldn't return the first one only, and we wouldn't return the first 3 grouped with the last 2. That's essentially how my code in ruby is working right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What MySQL does makes perfectly sense. What you want to do does not make sense:

- if you have let's say 4 items, each with price of 5 and you put `HAVING AVERAGE <= 7` what you say is that the query should return **ALL** the permutations, like:

  - {1} - since item with id 1, can be a group by itself
  - {1,2}
  - {1,3}
  - {1,4}
  - {1,2,3}
  - {1,2,4}

  ...

  - and so on?

Your algorithm of computing the average in ruby is also not valid, if you have items with values 5, 1, 7, 10 - and seek for an average value of less than 7, element with value 10 can be returned just in a group with element of value 1. But, by your algorithm (if I understood correctly), element with value 1 is returned in the first group.

**Update**

What you want is something like the [Knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) and your approach is using some kind of [Greedy Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greedy_algorithm) to solve it. I don't think there are straight, easy and correct ways to implement that in SQL.

After a google search, I found [this article](http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2011/02/22/and-now-for-a-completely-inappropriate-use-of-sql-server/) which tries to solve the knapsack problem with AI written in SQL.

By considering your item price as a weight, having the number of items and the desired average, you could compute the maximum value that can be entered in the 'knapsack' by multiplying `desired_cost` with `number_of_items`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That is a good explanation of what's going on, but please see my updated question for clarifications. For example we might have a target quantity of "3" in which case there would be one "right" answer: {1,2,3}. I do want to do things such as finding the "nearest match" if an exact match is not found, but that can be done with additional queries.

Comment: Thanks once again. I think you really nailed the problem at hand. I'm not sure if my original approach was correct but you've certainly pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

I would do almost an inverse of what Jasper provided... Start your query with your criteria to explicitly limit the few items that MAY qualify instead of getting all items and running a sub-select on each entry.  Could pose as a larger performance hit... could be wrong, but here's my offering..

```
select
      i2.*
   from
      ( SELECT  i.id
           FROM items i
           WHERE 
                 i.issue_date > 2011 
             AND i.listed = 1
             AND i.state_id = 5
           GROUP BY
              i.id
           HAVING 
              AVG( i.price) <= 500 ) PreQualify

      JOIN items i2
         on PreQualify.id = i2.id
             AND i2.issue_date > 2011 
             AND i2.listed = 1
             AND i2.state_id = 5
   order by
      i2.price desc
   limit
      25
```

Not sure of the order by, especially if you wanted grouping by item...  In addition, I would ensure an index on (state_id, Listed, id, issue_date)

CLARIFICATION per comments

I think I AM correct on it.  Don't confuse "HAVING" clause with "WHERE".  WHERE says DO or DONT include based on certain conditions.  HAVING means after all the where clauses and grouping is done, the result set will "POTENTIALLY" accept the answer.  THEN the HAVING is checked, and if IT STILL qualifies, includes in the result set, otherwise throws it out.  Try the following from the INNER query alone... Do once WITHOUT the HAVING clause, then again WITH the HAVING clause...

```
SELECT  i.id, avg( i.price )
   FROM items i
   WHERE i.issue_date > 2011 
     AND i.listed = 1
     AND i.state_id = 5
   GROUP BY
      i.id
   HAVING 
      AVG( i.price) <= 500
```

As you get more into writing queries, try the parts individually to see what you are getting vs what you are thinking... You'll find how / why certain things work.  In addition, you are now talking in your updated question about getting multiple IDs and prices at apparent low and high range... yet you are also applying a limit.  If you had 20 items, and each had 10 qualifying records, your limit of 25 would show all of the first item and 5 into the second... which is NOT what I think you want... you may want 25 of each qualified "id".  That would wrap this query into yet another level...

Comment: Looks good, but I think it has a similar problem to Jasper's. The AVG(i.price) does not really get the AVG of the total set of items. If you group by state_id it's perhaps more appropriate, but it won't find you the X items that fall under AVG 500, it will basically just tell give you a positive result IF all items from state_id=5 have an AVG <= 500.

Comment: @Kaptron, Then remove the "State_ID" qualifier from the internal... Whatever your INTERNAL query to get the average basis IS will return whatever 1 ID you want.  Then use THAT result to re-join out and put your other criteria the DOES include your State_ID element.

Comment: Perhaps I'm still not being entirely clear.Tudor's answer seemed to understand the problem. Essentially I'm trying to do a query where the total items *average* out to <= 500, meaning it could include items of prices 490, 500, and 510. The queries I've seen here only will include items that individually have prices <=500 rather than averaging out to 500 over the whole set.

Comment: @kaptron, revised answer for clarification.

Comment: @DRapp, my feeling is just that kaptron isn't being clear enough in his question (and his sample dataset is extremely biased as well). I think he might be looking for a query which varies the number of tuples returned depending on the values of the tuples. However, that's merely a guess, so I think we should just wait for kaptron to explain his goal more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure from your question, but I think this is a solution to your problem:

```
SELECT * FROM items 
WHERE (some "conditions", e.g. issue_date > 2011 and listed=1) 
 AND state_id = 5
 AND id IN (SELECT id
            FROM items
            GROUP BY id
            HAVING AVG(price) <= 500)

ORDER BY price DESC
LIMIT 25
```

note: This is off the top of my head and I haven't done complex SQL in a while, so it might be wrong. I think this or something like it should work, though.

Comment: Yeah I've tried something similar; the problem is that the "HAVING AVG(price) <=" in that query is essentially the same as "WHERE price <=" since it's just grouping by the individual item.

Comment: I made a database with the dataset you provided and the query returns what I thought you were looking for. I'm not sure I understand what you are looking for in that case. Could you try to explain what you do want?